# How to get rid of random new line in text file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code will take the contents of 'out.txt' and append it to the end of 'fixed_inv.txt' in the form of a new file, 'concat.txt' based on
a shared path.

Sample lines of all files:

1) fixed_inv.txt

```
 70 abc.def.com HRShared$   \vol\cor_q_share1\HRShared  34  NULL    3   4479242 Share   1   1   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:Up-level share detected.   0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
 70 abc.def.com HRTraining$ \vol\cor_q_share1\HRTraining    35  NULL    4   4479243 Share   1   1   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:Up-level share detected.   0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
 70 abc.def.com psoft_prd$  \vol\cor_q_share1\psoft_prd 36  NULL    6   4479245 Share   1   1   CifsPerm: 0, CifsType: 0, Remark:Up-level share detected.   0   CIFS    NULL    ntap
```

2) out.txt

```
abcdef.ghi.com: \fs\FS11\cifs15\cifs-userhome-corp-prd_01: The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (125), Access to file was denied (1)
abcdef.ghi.com: \fs\FS11\cifs17\cifs-userhome-corp-prd_03: The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (45)
abcdef.ghi.com: \fs\FS11\cifs17\cifs-userhome-corp-prd_05: The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (17)
```

3) concat.txt --> goal

In the 'concat.txt' file, I am getting a few rows (out of thousands) that seem to have a random new line in the middle of said line.

For instance, a line is supposed to look like:

```
122 abc.def.com Failed to get CIFS shares with error code -2147024891.  None Non-supported share access type.   0   Unkonwn NULL    bluearc Different Security Type (1), Access is denied. (1354), Pruned. Different security type (21), The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (3713), Could not convert the name of inner file or directory (27)
```

But instead, I have a few looking like:

```
122 abc.def.com Failed to get CIFS shares with error code -2147024891. None 
Non-supported share access type.   0   Unkonwn NULL    bluearc Different Security Type (1), Access is denied. (1354), Pruned. Different security type (21), The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (3713), Could not convert the name of inner file or directory (27)
```

Here's a sample of a bunch of lines (including an error line):
[image]
I have tried to fix this in my code below, but for some reason the code runs but does not fix the issue - which is to backspace the misplaced half line back or to get rid of the random new line.

```
class Error:
    def __init__ (self, path, message): #self = new instance of class
        self.path = path
        self.message = message #error message
        self.matched = False #has the path from out.txt been matched to the path of fixed_inv.txt?

def open_files(file1, file2, file3):
    try:
        f1 = open(file1, 'r')
    except IOError: 
        print("Can't open {}".format(file1))
        return None, None, None #you can't just open one file you have to open all
    else:
        try:
            f2 = open(file2, 'r')
        except IOError: 
            print("Can't open {}".format(file2))
            f1.close()
            return None, None, None
        else:
            try:
                f3 = open(file3, 'w')
            except IOError: 
                print("Can't open {}".format(file3))
                f1.close()
                f2.close()
                return None, None, None
            else:
                return f1, f2, f3

def concat(file1, file2, file3):
    errors = {} #key: path, value: instance of class Error
    f1, f2, f3 = open_files(file1, file2, file3)
    prevLine = "" #NEW
    if f1 is not None: #if file one is able to open...
        with f1:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(f1): #get the line number and line
                line = line.replace("\\", "/") #account for the differences in backslashes
                tokens = line.strip().split(': ') #strip white spaces, split based on ':'
                if len(tokens) != 3: #if there's less than two tokens...
                    print('Error on line {} in file {}: Expected three tokens, but found {}'.format(line_num + 1, file1, len(tokens))) #error
                else: #NEW
                    if line.startswith('Non-supported'): #NEW
                        Prevline = line
                        Prevline = line.strip('\n') #NEW
                    else:
                        errors[tokens[1]] = Error(tokens[1], tokens[2]) 
        with f2: 
            with f3:
                for line_num, line in enumerate(f2):
                    line = line.replace("\\", "/").strip() #account for the differences in backslashes
                    tokens_2 = line.strip().split('\t') #strip white spaces, split based on tab
                    if len(tokens_2) < 4: #if we are unable to obtain the path by now since the path should be on 3rd or 4th index
                        print('Error on line {} in file {}: Expected >= 4 tokens, but found {}'.format(line_num + 1, file2, len(tokens_2)))
                        f3.write('{}\n'.format(line))
                    else: #if we have enough tokens to find the path...
                        if tokens_2[3] in errors: #if path is found in our errors dictionary from out.txt...
                            line.strip('\n')
                            path = tokens_2[3] #set path to path found
                            msg = errors[path].message #set the class instance of the value to msg                    
                            errors[path].matched = True #paths have been matched
                            f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, msg)) #write the line and the error message to concat
                        else: #if path is NOT found in our errors dictionary from out.txt...
                            f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, 'None'))  
                            print('Error on line {} in file {}: Path {} not matched'.format(line_num + 1, file2, tokens_2[3])) #found in fixed_inv.txt,
                            #but not out.txt

                """for e in errors: #go through errors
                    if errors[e].matched is False: #if no paths have been matched
                        print('Path {} from {} not matched in {}'.format(errors[e].path, file1, file2)) #found in out.txt, but not in fixed_inv
                        f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, 'No error present'))

def main():

    file1 = 'out.txt'
    file2 = 'fixed_inv.txt'
    file3 = 'test_concat.txt'

    concat(file1, file2, file3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using windows 7 and any ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated! I asked this previously, but none of the answers were solutions that worked. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to safely handle files, use them in a ``with`` statement. That closes them regardless of errors.

Comment: You say that the problem is "broken" lines in `concat.txt` (the output file), but in your code you seem to be trying to detect and fix broken lines in `out.txt` (one of the input files).  Which is it?